# Intellij IDEA Remote Debug invalid breakpoints

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

**Hello, everybody!**

I am trying to debug my java8 application running on tomcat 7 with Intellij IDEA Remote Debug.
The problem is when i run debug in idea all off my breakpoints are set to invalid with message:

> Line numbers info is not available in class *pathToClass*

Here is my JAVA_OPTS settings from catalina.bat:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999 %JSSE_OPTS%"
```

[Here is my remote debug settins from IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjcEr.jpg)

Comment: I have a feeling that you're source code that you are debugging is different from the code running in tomcat. can you try doing a fresh deployment with what you have and try to check again. Basically, if you have, for example, 3 consecutive lines of code, and you put 3 breakpoints on each line, if one of the lines shows a breakpoint icon with an `X` on it, your code is not matching the one deployed in tomcat.

Comment: @sfat just redeployed and still the same. None of my breakpoints are enabled(

Comment: Are your deployment compiled with debug information _on_?  (method breakpoints should work regardless)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen can you explain please what does it mean? Method breakpoints wokr well

Comment: is breakpoints disabled by you by mistake , can you check it in debugger window of intelliJ?

Comment: At one point in your build process your Java code is compiled in to classes with the `javac` compiler (or something equivalent).  There is an option to the compiler to include debug information (including line numbers) which you apparently do not have enabled at the moment.  How do you compile your code?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal sorry its my mistake, breakpoints are invalid, not disabled

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i compile it with ant:
`<target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath" source="1.8" target="1.8" encoding="utf8"/>
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${resource.dir}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>`

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Just added `debug="true"` to my javac and it works fine

Comment: @bearbeard If this is a new project and not legacy code you have inherited, I will strongly recommend that you learn Maven and migrate to that instead of using Ant.   It takes a while getting used to but the long term benefits outweigh that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At one point in your build process your Java code is compiled in to classes with the javac compiler (or something equivalent). There is an option to the compiler to include debug information (including line numbers) which you apparently do not have enabled at the moment.

For plain `javac` add `-g`.

For ant add `debug="true"` to the `javac` task.

For Maven, the default configuration for the maven-compiler-plugin adds debug information, so the explicit setting not to has to be undone.

Answer (score 2):

> At one point in your build process your Java code is compiled in to
>   classes with the javac compiler (or something equivalent). There is an
>   option to the compiler to include debug information (including line
>   numbers) which you apparently do not have enabled at the moment. How
>   do you compile your code? – Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen

Adding `debug="true"` option to javac solving this problem.
Thanks everybody who helped.

Comment: Just put this as a comment under the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But the accepted answer did not solve it for me. In my case, the root cause was an interference caused by clover gradle plugin.

To debug the issue, I compared the source code of class `A.java` with the decompiled code of `A.class`. The decompiled version had a bunch of junk generated by clover. I just removed the clover plugin from the project, deleted the `build` folder, invalidated the cache and restarted IDEA. I added the breakpoint and ran it in debug. Voila! It worked this time.

It may not be clover in your case; It could be something else. But, most probably, this breakpoints issue is caused by a mismatch between your source code and compiled class. The best way to verify is to compare the decompiled class with its source.

Comment: Thanks. This was indeed the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the minify. Go to your Gradle and set:

```
Enabled=false
buildShrinkResources=false
```

Then sync and debug again.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a problem like that, lines were out of sync with a remote server, although the connection was established(I was able to see thread list in IDEA).

The first thing I tried was to put breakpoints not on statements, but on the whole method. Debug hit the breakpoint, but in a weird place(on closing curly brace).

All I had to do, is to remove one empty line from the start of my file, and everything just got aligned with remote.